# IOS - Table View not getting loaded

Tags: ios4

Hey i am new to iOS development, in my app i want to fetch video file from document folder to table view. But the files are not getting load in table view. so please tell me where am i making a mistake..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *docDirPath = NSHomeDirectory();
    docDirPath = [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSArray *filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docDirPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"filelist = %@",filelist);
    int count = [filelist count];
    NSString *currentFileName;
    videoListNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int j = 0; j<count; j++) 
    {
        currentFileName = (NSString *)[filelist objectAtIndex:j];
        if ([[currentFileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@".avi"]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"currentFileName = %@",currentFileName);
            [videoListNames addObject:currentFileName];
        }
    }
    [tblView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return videoListNames.count;
}


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    //TRY TO REMOVE ALL CONTENT
    for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    //cell.backgroundView.frame = 
    cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)[videoListNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"cell text = %@",cell.textLabel.text);
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you forgotten to set:

```
tblView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: see another problem is you are setting `cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)[assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in cellForRowAtIndexPath but you have not populated `assets` array in `viewDidLoad` you have populated `videoListNames` but have commented out the line in cellforrowatindexpath